# Creating Legends in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js

I'm trying to add a legend to a simple choropleth map using the ui for custom legends. But I'm not sure where to put it in my code, if it should  be within the createLayer function, or outside of it, etc.

Here's the code I'm using to create the legend:

```
      window.onload = function() {
    // Adds our custom legend
    var customLegend = new cdb.geo.ui.Legend.Custom({
      title: "Population Per Square Kilometer",
      data: [
        { name: "5",  value: "#E3EFC0" },
        { name: "15",       value: "#D8EAA2" },
        { name: "25",         value: "#CDE584" },
        { name: "50",         value: "#C2E066" },
        { name: "400 ",          value: "#B7DB48" },
        { name: "600",  value: "#ACD62A" },
        { name: "800",       value: "#90B424" },
        { name: "1000",         value: "#78961E" },
        { name: "5000",         value: "#21004A" },
        { name: "17470",          value: "#485A12" }
      ]
    });
    $(".legends").append(customLegend.render().$el);
  };

  cartodb.createVis('map', { 
    legends: false,
    zoom: 3,
    no_cdn: true
  })
```

This works, and the legend shows up just fine, but for some reason the rest of my map doesn't show up. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm messing up the order somehow and they rest of the map isn't initializing properly.

Here's my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position:relative;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- layer SQL -->
    <script type="text/sql" id="sql">
      SELECT * FROM us_counties
    </script>

    <!-- layer CartoCSS style -->
    <style type="text/cartocss" id="cartocss">

    <!-- CSS for legend -->
    .legend-selector {
        position:absolute;
        top: 20px; right: 20px;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        z-index: 100;
      }

      .legend-selector li {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0;
        list-style:none;
      }

      .legend-selector li a {
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        font: normal 13px "Helvetica",Arial;
        color: #858585;
        webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 0 4px 2px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 0 4px 2px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 0 4px 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -ms-border-radius: 4px;
        -o-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background: #FFF;
        z-index: 5;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .legend-selector li a.selected {
        background:#f1f1f1;
      }

      <!-- CSS for map -->

    #us_counties{
            polygon-fill: #8A4E8A;
            polygon-opacity: 0.8;
            polygon-comp-op: darken;
            line-color: #FFF;
            line-width: 0.3;
            line-opacity: 1;

    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm >= 17470] {
       polygon-fill: #485A12;
    }      }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 5000] {
       polygon-fill: #21004A;
    }     
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 1000] {
       polygon-fill: #78961E;
    }     
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 800] {
       polygon-fill: #90B424;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 600] {
       polygon-fill: #ACD62A;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 400] {
       polygon-fill: #B7DB48;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 50] {
       polygon-fill: #C2E066;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 25] {
       polygon-fill: #CDE584;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 15] {
       polygon-fill: #D8EAA2;
    }
    #us_counties [ pop_sqkm <= 5] {
       polygon-fill: #E3EFC0;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="legend-selector"> </ul>
    <div id="map">
    <div class="legends"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    (function () {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var sublayer
        var map = L.map('map', {
          zoomControl: true,
          center: [40, -98],
          zoom: 4
        });
        // add a baselayer
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        }).addTo(map);
        cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          user_name: 'samuelsmaggie',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
            sql: $('#sql').html(),
            cartocss: $('#cartocss').html(),
          }]
        },{
        })

        /*add to map and debug*/
        .addTo(map)
        .on('done', function(layer) {
          console.log(layer);
        })
        .on('error', function(e){
          console.log('error: '+e);
        });
      });
    })();

          window.onload = function() {
            // Adds our custom legend
            var customLegend = new cdb.geo.ui.Legend.Custom({
              title: "Population Per Square Kilometer",
              data: [
                { name: "5",  value: "#E3EFC0" },
                { name: "15",       value: "#D8EAA2" },
                { name: "25",         value: "#CDE584" },
                { name: "50",         value: "#C2E066" },
                { name: "400 ",          value: "#B7DB48" },
                { name: "600",  value: "#ACD62A" },
                { name: "800",       value: "#90B424" },
                { name: "1000",         value: "#78961E" },
                { name: "5000",         value: "#21004A" },
                { name: "17470",          value: "#485A12" }
              ]
            });
            $(".legends").append(customLegend.render().$el);
          };

          cartodb.createVis('map', { 
            legends: false,
            zoom: 3,
            no_cdn: true
          })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Should I try to put it within the createLayer function? Or somewhere else?